# How can I print all lines generated in a given time interval in sed

Tags: sed

I have to print all lines from /var/log/messages that were generated between 11pm and
12 midnight.
I used this code

```
sed -n -e '/23:00:00/,/00:00:00/p' /var/log/messages
```

But output is not displaying.I tried for another time interval.It works only when the accurate time in the message file is given.

eg:`sed -n -e '/23:50:01/,/23:59:09/p' /var/log/messages`

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because 23:00:00 doesn't show in /var/log/message.

you can try this:

`sed -n -e '/23:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]/, /00:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]/p' /var/log/messages`

Comment: Here time upto 12:59:59 AM is accepted.My query is in between 11PM and 12AM

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -r -e '/ (00:00:00|23:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]) /p' /var/log/messages
```

If you don't need the messages at 00:00:00 then just use

```
sed -n -e '/ 23:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] /p' /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Both the above commands are working for me in both ubuntu and linux. Can you please paste some sample lines from your /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `awk`

```
awk '$0>=from && $0<=to' from="23:00:00" to="00:00:00" /var/log/messages
```